# Potential security issues with localhost index directory?

Tags: php, security, localhost

I recently viewed a video guide about setting up for laravel development. WAMP and laravel were both installed. After the instructor completeted the install he navigated to the localhost directory, and claimed that having the localhost index displaying the file structure of your project was "a huge security issue", and proceeded to setup a vhost to rectify the problem.

I'm uncertain because 127.0.0.1 I believe is only accessible from the local machine. If an attacker can access it then he would already have control of my computer anyway. What other ways might this be a vulnerability?

Thanks.

Comment: not a security issue on localhost at all, and while not the best idea not a security issue on 'global' hosted either

Comment: Don't generally trust statements without some justification.

Comment: If you've got your local development environment exposed to the public internet you've got bigger troubles than a directory listing.

Answer (score 0):

If it is only accessible from your local machine, there is no security issue because there are no possible attackers. If it is accessible from a network, you should change it to be only accessible from your local, until you've taken security measurements.